# Using System.Web.Mail and System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

We have a website which we have re-designed and coded to work using `System.Net.Mail` but other parts of our website use `System.Web.Mail`

We have specified the namespaces to be used in our web.config file but as we are specifying both `System.Net.Mail` and `System.Web.Mail` and they both use `MailMessage` it throws an error

```
'MailMessage' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.Mail, System.Net.Mail'.
```

Is there anyway to avoid this error and still use both namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the namespace to state which namespace you wish to refer in the type declaration like:

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage NewWebMessage = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
```

and

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage NewNetMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add fully qualified name to one of the usage of namespace. For ex

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage messageObject=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage()
```